# Default argument to function only if condition is met

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing

I am currently writing a function that I want to pass default arguments if a condition is met. If the condition is not met, no argument should be passed. How can I achieve this? 
I tried it with ifelse and NULL like in this minimal example but it did not work:

```
my_function <- function(.data,
                        .variable = ifelse("var1" %in% names(.data), "var1", NULL)){
  ...
}
```

If "var1" is no variable name of .data and I don't pass another argument on .variable, I want to get an error like "argument ".variable" is missing, with no default". My solution works but I get other error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not doing it directly in the default argument, but at the start of the function, with something along the lines of:

```
my_function <- function(.data,
                        .variable = NULL) {
  if (is.null(.variable)) {
    if ("var1" %in% names(.data)) {
      .variable = "var1" 
    } else {
      stop(".variable undefined with no suitable default")
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: That's what I did now. I only thought you can achieve it in the default argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `ifelse` doesn't like having `NULL` as the response in the case the condition is `FALSE`:

```
ifelse(2 < 1, 1, NULL)
# Error in ans[!test & ok] <- rep(no, length.out = length(ans))[!test &  : 
#   replacement has length zero
# In addition: Warning message:
# In rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) :
#   'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

It seems to come from the fact that `ifelse` returns

> A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and
>   "class") as test and data values from the values of yes or no.

and

> If yes or no are too short, their elements are recycled.

Seeing `rep` in the error message and the fact that `length(NULL)` is zero seems to be a good evidence. So, instead you may want to use, e.g.,

```
my_function <- function(.data, .variable = if("var1" %in% names(.data)) "var1" else NULL)
  is.null(.variable)

my_function("1")
# [1] TRUE
```

See `?ifelse` for other warnings.